# I cannot add a new Server Role "SQL Server 2008 R2"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to add a new user-defined Server Role to my SQL Server instance, but the menu doesn't show all options, it only shows this:

[image]

Instead of this :

[image]

and I also tried the T-SQL command to create the server role but it keep showing the message

> Incorrect Syntax near 'AUTHORIZATION', expecting id ,quoted_id or to.

Please Help ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CREATE SERVER ROLE only apply to SQL Server 2012 through current version.

See on MSDN: [CREATE SERVER ROLE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677610.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) you saved me from a tons of wasted minutes.