# Cannot add new Server Role SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, role

It seems that I have the same problem as Yasser in this post

[I cannot add a new Server Role "SQL Server 2008 R2"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119520/i-cannot-add-a-new-server-role-sql-server-2008-r2)

but I am running SQL Server 2014.

Basically when I right click on Server Roles I only get a menu with three options, "Start Power Shell, Reports, Refresh".

The command CREATE SERVER ROLE works. I am logged in as "sa". Any advice would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Management Studio are you using (from Help > About)? Is it the Express edition?

Comment: Yes it is the Express Edition and the version is 12.0.2. Does the express edition have limited functionality?

Comment: And are you sure the engine you are connecting to is 2012 or better? What is `SELECT @@VERSION;`? Can you show a screen shot of Object Explorer that includes the server/version?

Comment: Right click on "security" and select "new" then "server role".

Comment: FWIW I also see this problem (when connecting to Express Edition instances only).

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in Management Studio, and has existed since at least SQL Server 2012. Unlike other missing things in Management Studio (like SQL Server Agent), this has nothing to do with the version or edition of Management Studio you're using, but rather the edition of SQL Server that Object Explorer has connected to. Here's confirmation from one of the lead SSMS devs:

[image]

You will need to use T-SQL for this functionality until they fix it (which I think after 2016 SP1 they'll need to do a full audit of any instance-specific filtering or restrictions).